# select field from html form in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I create an HTML form to register users, but I have a problem with the gender field:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <select name="gender">
            <option hidden>Gender</option>
            <option value="0">Male</option>
            <option value="1">Female</option>
            <option value="2">Prefer not to say</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

my `forms.py` file

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    GENDER = [
        ("0", "Male"),
        ("1", "Female"),
        ("2", "Other")
    ]

gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER)
```

I am trying to get the valid data in my view below:

```
def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("hello")
```

i can't give `is_valid()` for this part of html

- my view is class-based.

I tried without `<select>` and `{{ form.gender }}` and it worked, but when i use `<select>` in HTML, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fields widget:
`forms.py`

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    GENDER = [
        ("0", "Male"),
        ("1", "Female"),
        ("2", "Other")
    ]

    gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='Gender' ,widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=GENDER)) # new
```

Comment: it did not work